# Randomize multiple integers to equal variable

Tags: javascript, html, integer

Using JavaScript, how would I go about generating 30 random integers and have the sum of those 30 integers be 60000? I need the script to produce a different set of numbers each time it is run, making sure that the total is always 60000

```
var n = 30;
var total = 60000;
var min = 10;
var max = 5000;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
  // Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min); ??
}
```

In order to avoid excessively large and small numbers, the min and max values will likely be needed

Comment: Yes. Its not a point of language but logic. Once you have algo, you can achieve this in any language. Also, sorry if this is rude, but a user with your rep should know essentials parts of a question

Comment: This much is obvious. How is it done?

Comment: As said, please add your effort first. *code/algo/reference links* anything, but your effort is mandatory

Comment: What does this mean: "randomizing the outcome of 30 integers"? You want to generate 30 random integers and have the sum of those 30 integers be 60000?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: @EvanTrimboli *randomizing 3 int equal to 10* can be `[4,3,3]` or `[5,3,1]` or `[9,1,0]` or even `[10,0,0]`. He wishes to get one such pair

Comment: So what if you happen to get the first 29 numbers be `1`? Do you just loop forever until you happen to generate `59971`? How random is the randomness supposed to be?

Comment: I need the script to produce a different set of numbers each time it is run, making sure that the total is always 60000

Comment: Do you have any other requirements regarding the range or uniformity of the numbers? It's somewhat hard to make all of the numbers totally random because if you generate 29 numbers the last number can't be random anymore because it must be exactly 60000-(sum of previous 29). If you want truly random numbers and distribution it'll have to be some other method.

Comment: No other requirements. After each loop, couldn't you reduce the total by the previous random integer? and when n = 30. The remainder = 60000 - the 29 integers

Comment: Yes, like I said. And the last number will not be random. It's likely to be on average much smaller or much bigger than the other numbers.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand now :) So putting a range of say, min = 10, max = 5000, would make more sense then...

Comment: Depending on the uniformity of the results you could come up with some dynamic programming solution to bound the random number within some range each iteration of the loop depending on what you get back.

Comment: @JJJ about last value being not random, sum of 29 random numbers will yield you unique total and in turn a unique difference. Will it not?

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, but it won't have the same range or distribution as the other numbers. If you choose the other numbers between 0 and 4000, the last number will be between -60000 and 60000. It's also not uniformly random between that range, but getting something around 2000 is much more likely than something in the fringes, whereas the other numbers are equally likely to have any value between 0 and 4000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic

- Accept Max total and total number of resulting Numbers.
- Now loop based on this `number - 1` for `n-1` random numbers and last value should be `max - currentSum`. Since rest of numbers are random, this difference will also be random and this will also ensure total being equal.
- Now all you need to do is return a random number based on a given range.

I have also added a flag to check for unique values. Currently I have just added `1` to it but this will not ensure its uniqueness, but as its out of scope, not rectifying it.

**Code**

```js
function getRandomInRange(max) {
  var raiseVal = Math.pow(10, (max.toString().length - 1) || 1);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * raiseVal) % max;
}

function getRandomNumbers(max, n, uniqueNum) {
  var nums = [];
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    let r = getRandomInRange(max - sum);
    if(uniqueNum && nums.indexOf(r) > -1){
      r += 1;
    }
    
    nums.push(r)
    sum += r;
    
  }
  nums.push(max - sum);
  console.log(nums)
  return nums
}

getRandomNumbers(3, 3, true)
getRandomNumbers(3, 3)
getRandomNumbers(1000, 10)
getRandomNumbers(600000, 30)
```

Comment: The results aren't uniformly random, as you can see from the last test: almost every time you get large numbers at the start and smaller numbers at the end. But since the OP said that there are no requirements on that front then maybe this fits their purposes.

Comment: @JJJ Yes. Even I noticed that after your previous comment.